# Bold last row - using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am running a batch script to convert a CSV in to a HTML file however I need to make the last row bold, but I have tried different things to bold the last row but I have not been able to get the script to determine if its the last row or not.

Any thoughts?

```
@echo off
Title Convert csv file to HTML file
Rem Set what is your delimiters in your csv file like [,] [;] [:] [|] or [tab]
set "delims=,"
Rem Set the name of the CSV file into a variable
set "CSV_File=FinalReportFormatted.csv" 
Rem Set the name of the HTML output file from CSV file into variable
for %%a in ("%CSV_File%") do set "HTML_File=%%~na.html"
if exist "%HTML_File%" del /f /q "%HTML_File%"
Call :CreateHTMLtable "%CSV_File%" "%HTML_File%"

exit /b
::******************************************************************************************************
:CreateHTMLTable <inputfile> <outputfile>
setlocal 
(
 echo ^<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC 
 echo "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 echo  "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd"^>
 echo ^<HTML^>
 echo ^<HEAD^>
 echo ^<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" 
 echo CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8"^>
 echo ^</HEAD^>
 echo ^<BODY^>
 echo ^<style type="text/css"^>
 echo .tftable {font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:100%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #bcaf91;border-collapse: collapse;}
 echo .tftable th {font-size:12px;background-color:#fff;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #bcaf91;text-align:center;}
 echo .tftable tr {background-color:#ffffff;}
 echo .tftable td {font-size:12px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #bcaf91; text-align:center;}
 echo .tftable tr:hover {background-color:#ffffff;}
 echo ^</style^>
 echo ^<p^>
 echo ^<Dear All,^>
 echo ^</p^>
 echo ^<center^>^<table class="tftable" border="1"^>
)>%2

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('Type "%~1"') do (
 set "var=%%A"
 set "var=!var:&=&amp;!"
 set "var=!var:<=&lt;!"
 set "var=!var:>=&gt;!"
 set "var=!var:%delims%=</td><td>!"
 echo ^<tr^>^<td^>!var!^</td^>^</tr^>
)>>%2

(
 echo ^</table^>^</center^>
 echo ^</BODY^>
 echo ^</HTML^>
)>>%2
endlocal
::******************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: You could preliminary count a number of lines in CSV and then use this number to detect the last line.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're interested, but are you aware that Windows OS's have for many years now had `PowerShell` built-in. Using that you could run, `Import-CSV 'FinalReportFormatted.csv' | ConvertTo-HTML >"FinalReportFormatted.html"`. Whilst I'm aware that the output from this basic command is not exactly what you want, were you to take a look at the commands you would probably find that with a little modification/expansion it would perform the task more easily and efficiently than trying to use batch files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Compo that using PowerShell is the more forward-looking approach,
but as the batch seems to work well, implement monotero's suggestion:

- count lines of the .csv file with `find /V /C "" <"%~1"`
- parse that number and store in variable `Lines`
- modify the middle part of the sub `:CreateHTMLTable` with downcounting Lines
- if (remaining) Lines greater 0 proceed as before
- if not insert `<B>`,`</B>` tags.

---

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('find.exe /V /C "" ^<"%~1"') Do Set Lines=%%A
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('Type "%~1"') do (
 set "var=%%A"
 set "var=!var:&=&amp;!"
 set "var=!var:<=&lt;!"
 set "var=!var:>=&gt;!"
 Set /A Lines-=1
 if !Lines! gtr 0 (
   set "var=!var:%delims%=</td><td>!"
   echo ^<tr^>^<td^>!var!^</td^>^</tr^>
 ) else (
   set "var=!var:%delims%=</B></td><td><B>!"
   echo ^<tr^>^<td^>^<B^>!var!^</B^>^</td^>^</tr^>
 )
)>>%2
```

[image]